# Similar boundary but different spatial resolution

Tags: qgis, dem, qgis-processing, multi-resolution-raster

I am not sure if I can express it properly considering the lingo but, I am trying to create maps that show comparison of different spatial resolution in determining soil loss in a given watershed. I have 30m, 90m and 1km DEM spatial resolution. Now, I created a watershed boundary and clipped DEM using 30m resolution. The problem at hand is that whenever I tried to clip the 90m and 1km resolution to the created watershed boundary, no clipped DEM can be found in the map since it is nearby a huge part of water. Another is whenever I tried to create watershed boundary on the respective resolution, I cannot generate any stream networks. Is the other DEM data simply too large to use considering the actual land area I'm trying to use is around 4,000 hectares? Or I am missing some process?

Comment: 1km resolution DEM is unlikely to be useful in a 4,000 hectare area. Certainly not for creating stream networks. Even 90m is not going to be great. I don't understand what you mean by "since it is nearby a huge part of water". You might want to include some screenshots to show what you mean.